# What is the name for this PCB process?

Tags: pcb-fabrication

Here's a picture of these curved circuit boards, this is from the inside of a keyboard.  https://diystuff.nl/embedded/advantage2-keyboard-teardown/

[image: picture of keyboard innards, source linked above]

It's not flex, and it's not flex-rigid. These boards are thick like a regular PCB 40-60 mil.  There's no kapton here. It's almost like they've been formed in place out of FR4 or some type of fiberglass. If you pull this board off the keyboard it doesn't flex although it is not as stiff as FR4. There's even through-hole components pushed through and soldered to it. I wonder if they solder and then bend under heat or if this is hand done (or maybe robotic these days).

It's been twenty years since I ran across a board house making this stuff and for the life of me I can't remember what it's called.

--Edit
This isn't what I was looking for exactly but this process is called semi-flex. They thin out a section of the FR4 and then bend it in MFG. I'd never seen this done before (it's not rigid-flex).

[image]

Comment: The site can't be reached. That's why you should "upload" images to your questions instead of linking to an external site, unless the question is related to the site itself. Data on external sites can be unreliable or moved.

Comment: If you heat the PCB to its glass temperature, you can rather easily impose and freeze such a modest curvature even into 1.6mm boards. However, I think it's easier to just use thinner, e.g. 0.6 mm ones and flex them using the mounting pins/glue

Answer (score 5):

Looks like conventional thin FR4 boards, bent after soldering and held by the plastic, as Marcus says.

There are some non-planar boards made for special applications (such as antennas) but they're not that.

This is very similar to the PCB described in [US 5,610,602](https://patentimages.storage.googleapis.com/51/1d/ac/c52d2e31bc14a7/US5610602.pdf)

[image]

As explained in the patent, the "fingers" allow the board to conform to curvature in two axis. Mathematically, it removes the restriction that the entire board be a [developable surface](https://web.mit.edu/hyperbook/Patrikalakis-Maekawa-Cho/node190.html).

Comment: Good find on the patent, there has to be a name for this approach :)

Comment: I gave you the best name I could find- "non-planar PCB".

Answer (score 1):

These are flex boards; they have no rigidity of their own and are rather thin. The curved form is defined by the rigid molded black plastic "hull".

Comment: no I'm not talking about flex boards.  They're much thicker than this and rigid when removed.